# How to raise an Exception while inserting to firebase if the data is not synced to server immediately?

Tags: android, firebase

I am inserting some values to Firebase. I want to mark the insert operation as failed if the data is not synced to server after a few second delay.
I tried `onCompleteListener`  and `onFailureListener`on `Task`, but `onFailureListener` doesn't fire if the device is offline then,`onCompleteListener` immediately fires after successful sync with firebase server (the device comes online). 
I want to fire the `onFailureListener` immediately if the device is offline. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check availability of network before inserting values by using the following function

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return info != null;
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can check if internet is working or not even if it's connected.

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context){
    if(isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            connection.setReadTimeout(1500);
            connection.connect();
            return (connection.getResponseCode() == 204 && connection.getContentLength() == 0);
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error checking internet connection");
        }
    } else Log.e("ERROR", "No network available");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: My app's users sometime use data connection only for accessing famous services such as Facebook, WhatsApp etc. and the data subscription they buy from the telecom operators are exclusively for using Facebook, WhatsApp etc. In that case, calling above function to check network availability returns true. But actually connectivity for my app or other apps (excluding Facebook app and WhatsApp) are not available. So, I want to check the low level write operation to the server was succeeded or not. In that case, your code won't work.

Comment: I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own exception or you can create your own listenerwith interface according to your requirement. if there will be no connectivity with the internet then it will help you to call your desired code.